# Selecting last value to be entered each month

Tags: mariadb, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, where, max

I am looking to pull a closing balance from the database for each month.

I have tried

```
SELECT CloseBal As 'Balance', MONTHNAME(DateTime) as 'Month', DateTime
FROM Table1
WHERE MAX(DateTime)
Group By Month
```

I am getting an error `invalud use of grouping function`

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Read about "groupwise-max via the tag I added.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing time, depending on some details that were not provided here.

One of then is to use '*ROW_NUMBER*' as said in the comment above.
As an example:

```sql
   SELECT
       Balance,
       Month,
       DateTime
   FROM (
       SELECT 
           CloseBal As 'Balance', 
           MONTHNAME(DateTime) as 'Month', 
           DateTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', DateTime)
               ORDER BY DateTime DESC) as priority_row
       FROM 
           Table1) t1
   WHERE
       priority_row = 1
```

There are other possible solutions, but more details need to be provided.

Just an observation: for ANSI SQL, the variable '**Month**' doesn't exist until the query runs. Thus, you cannot call it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This looks like it could do what I am looking for, although my database doesnt seem to like `PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', DateTime)` I am using `MariaDB
What other info might you need from me to fine tune the answer?

Essentially, I am looking to the query to group by Month name... Find the last entry for each moth using the `DateTime` field and take the closing Balance which is noted in this field.

The answer above by @user580950 gives me the Month and MaxDate but the closing balance is incorrect as it takes the first entry in the month

Comment: I tried `DATEDIFF` in place of `DATE_TRUNC` It gives me only the closing Balance for February and leaves out January

Comment: I think I have found that the priority row is causing the issue when using DATEDIFF )I Have also tried using `DATE_FORMAT` which gives the same result.
`Priority_row` returns only one answer. Ideally I would like an output for each month.

Answer (score 0):

The error I think it because you're using the `MAX` function in the `WHERE` clause, try the following

```
SELECT CloseBal As 'Balance', MONTHNAME(DateTime) as 'Month', MAX(DateTime) as 'MaxDate'
FROM Table1
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(DateTime)
```

You can fine-tune the statement by joining the table with a subquery that returns the MAX DateTime for each MONTHNAME(DateTime):

```
SELECT t1.CloseBal As 'Balance', MONTHNAME(t1.DateTime) as 'Month', MAX(t1.DateTime) as 'MaxDate'
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN (
SELECT MONTHNAME(DateTime) as Month, MAX(DateTime) as MaxDate
FROM Table1
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(DateTime)
) t2
ON MONTHNAME(t1.DateTime) = t2.Month AND t1.DateTime = t2.MaxDate
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(t1.DateTime);
```

This should give you the closing balance that matches the **MAX(DateTime)** for each month.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This function returns the last entry date `MAX(DateTime) as 'MaxDate'`
However, the balance it shows is the first balance in the month rather than the balance that matches the `MAX(DateTime). Is there a way to fine tune this?

Comment: @Paulmcf1987 I have updated the answer